# Компиляция кода программы в один файл на macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, компиляция, mac

Имеется код программы в виде filename.py, как превратить его в файл, чтобы отправлять кому угодно и устанавливать на любом компе без компилятора Python? macOS

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Командная строка: `pyinstaller filename.py --onefile`
И всё в шокаладе)

[Официальный сайт PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/)

Comment: там вроде самараспаковывающийся архив получается..

Comment: У меня виндовс 8 как на macOS я не знаю поэтому и дал ссылку на сайт pyinstaller .После каких манипуляций получается архив ?

Comment: пайинсталер архив делает)

Comment: На чём ? на виндовс он делает exe-ник.

Comment: Exeшник и есть самораспаковывающийся архив. Я просто упомянул об этом так как режим onefile засрет временную папку

Comment: Ну её почистить не трудно) а ещё в pyinstaller есть опция --clear по моему она очищает всё это на счёт временной папки я не уверен.